# How can I convert an iso cd image to bin/cue format on a mac?

Tags: mac, conversion, iso-image, disk-image, bin-cue-image

How can I convert an iso cd image to bin/cue format on a mac? I did some Googling, but couldn't find a solution, ended up having to use some freeware tool for windows in a VM :/

Comment: If anyone found this post because they were trying to do the reverse (convert bin/cue to an iso) take a look here: http://jamesnsears.com/2007/04/convert_bin_cue_iso_on_mac_osx.php
 Worked for me. You can download bchunk and run "bchunk problemimage.bin problemimage.cue convertedimage.iso"

Answer (score 5):

PowerISO has a Mac command line utility for converting between ISO, BIN, DAA, and other formats.

http://www.poweriso.com/poweriso-1.3-osx.tar.gz

`poweriso convert input.img -o output.bin -ot bin`

Comment: Sadly, that link is for a 32-bit executable and won’t run in Catalina and beyond.

Comment: Try this: https://www.poweriso.com/download-poweriso-command-line-utility-for-osx.htm it works on M1 (64bit) Monterey

Answer (score 2):

LiquidCD can write CUE/BIN files. The process would be the same as actually creating an image from the disc.

- Mount ISO image on the Mac
- Point LiquidCD to the Mounted Image
- Write CUE/BIN File

I did this before to convert an ISO to a DMG.

---

As of this edit, April 14, 2020, the domain for LiquidCD, maconnect.ch, simply returns a `:-)` and no other content.

Comment: The iso image I'm converting also contains some CD audio tracks. Will they be converted as well with this method?

Comment: You will have to test and try, I am not sure. LiquidCD however does support extracting Music so it might be able to. I hardly ever deal with Audo CD's

Comment: I've been trying to rip some PS1 games to play in emulators for ages now, and this is the only program I could find that made working BIN/CUE images out of the ISOs I ripped with Disk Utility.

Answer (score 1):

[Toast Titanium](http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/toast/default.html) will do it, but its by no means free.

There's a handy little command line [tool](http://he.fi/bchunk/) to do BIN/CUE -> ISO, but I can't find one to do the reverse.

Comment: +1 ...that's what I was trying to do. Works great.

Answer (score -1):

FYI, Disk Utility built into OS X can burn .ISO files natively. Just select 'Burn' from the toolbar in Disk Utility and choose your .ISO file and Disk Utility will burn it, all without additional software

Comment: That's not what he's asking